# Sending and reading a 2D array using sockets Java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, server, client-server

I am trying to create a simple sever/client implementation. What I am trying to do is send a 2D array populated with random numbers from the client side to the server. The server would then find the average of each row of the 2D array and send back the max average of the arrays and display it. I have browsed multiple solutions on StackOverflow and none seem to work for me.

The problem I am having is with serialization and un- serialization of the array. Every time I try to run it I get a StreamCorruptedException error. I cant seem to get a grasp on ObjectoutputStreams and ObjectInputStreams. Can I please get a hint or two as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Here is my server side :

```
public class socket_sr  {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The server is running.");

        int clientNumber = 0;
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }


    private static class Capitalizer extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;
        private int clientNumber;

        public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
            log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
        }


        public void run() {
            try {


                InputStream is= socket.getInputStream();
               ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
               ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


                while (true) {
                     Double[][] arrayAvg = new Double[15][15000];
                    arrayAvg = (Double [][])in.readObject();
                    if (arrayAvg == null || in.equals(".")) {
                        break;
                    }
                  /********Do averaging***********/
                    int rowTotal=0;
                    int avg=0;
                    double average[] = new double [arrayAvg.length];
                    for (int row=0; row<arrayAvg.length; row++){
                         rowTotal = 0;
                        for(int col =0; col <arrayAvg[row].length; col++){
                        rowTotal+=arrayAvg[row][col];   

                        }
                        average[row] = rowTotal / arrayAvg[row].length;

                    }
                    Double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                    for(int i = 0; i < average.length; i++) {
                          if(average[i] > max) {
                             max = average[i];
                          }
                    }

                   //Here I am sending the max back to the client side.
                   out.writeObject(max);


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
                }
                log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Logs a simple message.  In this case we just write the
         * message to the server applications standard output.
         */
        private void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my client side:

```
public class socket_cl implements Serializable{



public void connectToServer() throws IOException {

    // Get the server address from a dialog box.


    // Make connection and initialize streams
    Socket socket = new Socket("Host", 9898);
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream   in =   new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);


    // Consume the initial welcoming messages from the server
    Double[][] arrays = new Double[15][15000];
    try {
        for(int i=0; i< 15; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<15000;j++){
            arrays[i][j]=Math.random()*100; 

        }

        }
    os.writeObject(arrays);
      //Grab the max from server and display it
    Double max= in.readObject();
     System.out.println(max);

            os.close();

        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Stopping Server");

}




public static void main(String[] args) {


  socket_cl cl = new socket_cl();
  try {
    cl.connectToServer();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}




}
```

}

The server is running.
New connection with client# 0 at Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=53215,localport=9898]

New connection with client# 1 at Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=53216,localport=9898]

Error handling client# 0: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 47455420

Connection with client# 0 closed

Error handling client# 1: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 47455420
Connection with client# 1 closed

New connection with client# 2 at Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=53217,localport=9898]

Error handling client# 2: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 47455420

Connection with client# 2 closed

Comment: can you put your error logs here? thank you

Comment: You don't need `implements Serializable` on your client. Also since double is not an object it can't implement serializable so you can't send it over stream like that. You must either make it `Double` so its an object and you can send it over. Or make another class that stores a `2D double array` and have that class implement `Serializable` Also on your client side i don't see you send anything but the `double[][]` but on your server you `accept()` more than one thing

Comment: Is there a better way that you would recommend passing a 2D array, something other than passing it as an object. @3kings

Comment: @harmanlitt Look at my answer below. That is kind of my recommendation. But you must send it as some form of object because it needs to be `Serializable`

Comment: @3kings I changed my code a little bit, do you mind taking one little look at it?

Comment: @harmanlitt yeah of course

Comment: @harman-litt Don't change your original code at this time. It may render some answers irrelevant.

Comment: @harmanlitt so what seems to be the problem? It worked for me but it took a very very long time and im assuming thats because of the fact that the array is quite big.

Comment: @3kings every time I refresh my localhost i get a StreamCorrupted Error. Approximately how minutes did it take for you.

Comment: @3kings how are you running the files? I run the server java file and then wait.

Comment: @harmanlitt umm i waited just a few seconds not too long. I run the server then the client and i wait for the Printlns that i put in at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have double in your arrays.  You may want to use the wrapper class Double so its an object.  It makes it much easier.  You can serialize primitives however there are certain restrictions in doing so.

https://www.quora.com/I-know-you-can-serialize-objects-in-Java-but-how-do-you-serialize-primitives-such-as-integers-or-doubles

In this forum they ask the same question I had about the primitives being serialized.  The solution they provide is...

> Primitives in Java have associated Wrapper Classes that "wrap" your primitive into an object. From there, you can serialize the object containing your primitive.

Wrapper classes.. E.g. Integer for int, Double for double etc.

Not sure if it will clear everything up however this is something you may want to correct in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have made a few adjustments to your classes please look below. I have commented things

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socket_sr 
{


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    System.out.println("The server is running.");

    int clientNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}


private static class Capitalizer extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;

    public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
    }


    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
           ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
           //System.out.println(in.readObject());   //you have this here which will read the Double[][]? 

            while (true) 
            {
                Double[][] arrayAvg = new Double[15][15000];
                arrayAvg = (Double [][])in.readObject();
                if (arrayAvg == null || in.equals("."))
                {
                    break;
                }
              /********Do averaging***********/
                int rowTotal=0;
                int avg=0;
                Double average[] = new Double [arrayAvg.length];
                for (int row=0; row<arrayAvg.length; row++)
                {
                    rowTotal = 0;
                    for(int col =0; col <arrayAvg[row].length; col++)
                    {
                        rowTotal+=arrayAvg[row][col];
                    }
                    average[row] = (double) (rowTotal / arrayAvg[row].length);
                }
                double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
                for(int i = 0; i < average.length; i++) 
                {
                      if(average[i] > max)
                      {
                         max = average[i];
                      }
                }
               // System.out.println((double)in.readObject());  This again won't work you are only sending one thing.
                //now you did all that stuff with it.... send back to client??
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);} 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();} 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");}
            log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs a simple message.  In this case we just write the
     * message to the server applications standard output.
     */
    private void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
}
```

Above is your server class and below is client

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socket_cl
{

public void connectToServer() throws IOException 
{

    // Get the server address from a dialog box.


    // Make connection and initialize streams
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9898);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


    // Consume the initial welcoming messages from the server
    Double[][] arrays = new Double[15][15000];
    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i< 15; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<15000;j++)
            {
                arrays[i][j]=Math.random()*100; 
            }

        }
        os.writeObject(arrays);

        //do you want to catch something here from the server? maybe the new Double[][]?  in.readObject?

        os.close();
        socket.close();
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println("Stopping Server");

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  socket_cl cl = new socket_cl();
  try 
  {
    cl.connectToServer();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  {e.printStackTrace();}

}
}
```